# restkit: lazy loading, deleting objects

Tags: restkit

I have to implement two different behaviours:
1. Lazy loading: download only required objects from server. Let's say I have a table view like in twitter app, scrolling should bring new objects.
My server takes "start" and "amount" arguments and returns the total amount. It also returns objects with some position ID, if that makes sense.
2. I need to delete some objects that are not returned from server anymore. So if local database have entities with IDs of 1-5 and server doesn't return object with id 3 – it should be deleted. There are two deleting scenarios: out of date (could be determined locally and set in a fetch controller) and deleted – couldn't be determined locally.
So how to downloaded deleted? Do I have to return some special objects from server?
3. One more thing: if user is viewing objects with IDs of 10000 – it's probably a good time to delete the first hundred locally. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to manage this yourself. The deletion support offered by RestKit isn't going to be enough to cover all of your requirements.

If you have a strong deletion requirement that can't be worked out locally then you either need to delete everything locally and refresh to be sure or have the server return a 'deleted' token that you can pick up and use.

Comment: What about lazy loading? How can I request objects only when they age going to shown?

Comment: That is string greed by you getting a delegate callback from the table view about scrolling (to the bottom). RestKit can't do that automatically.

Comment: **that is triggered by**